# VBA how to multiply by 6.555 every cell in entire column USD to DDK value

Tags: excel

This is my Data:

[image]

In VBA, how can I multiply by 6.555 every cell in entire column USD to DDK value?

Comment: If the "DKK" value in the upper-left is A2, `=IF(A2="usd",F2*6.555,F2)`. Drag down.

Comment: Improved question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming USD is in cel A5, using , as separator

```
=if(A5="USD",F5*6.555,F5)
```